# Is there a way to show a png image, using openCV, saved as a uchar buffer?

Tags: c++, opencv

My goal is to show an image given its png buffer, so lets say I have this file, sum.png, in the same folder as my project.
I read the image and load its data into an `unsigned char` vector.
I then proceed to construct a `cv::Mat` object from the `unsigned char` vector, but when i try to call `imshow()` on the image, i get the following error: `intrin_avx.hpp not found`.
Here's the code:

```
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    std::ifstream fileStream("sum.png", std::ios::binary | std::ios::in | std::ios::ate);

    // Check if the file path is valid
    if (!fileStream.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "Invalid file path!" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Get file size
    auto fileSize = fileStream.tellg();
    if (fileSize < 100) { std::cout << "File's too small";  return -1; }

    // Create the file buffer
    std::vector<unsigned char> fileBuffer(fileSize);

    // Read the file and load the buffer
    fileStream.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    fileStream.read((char*)fileBuffer.data(), fileSize);
    fileStream.close();

    cv::Mat img(cv::Size(1920, 1080), CV_8UC3, fileBuffer.data());
    cv::imshow("Window", img);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is your file large enough (1920 x 1080 x 3 = 6,220,800 bytes or larger)?

Comment: You may want to use [`cv::imdecode()`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.5/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga26a67788faa58ade337f8d28ba0eb19e).

Comment: how do i convert a unsigned char* to InputArray to use in imdecode?

Comment: Hope [this page helps](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html)

Comment: look at all constructors of `cv::Mat`. "InputArray" practically means cv::Mat